How can tell where this XSS payload gets triggered?
After running XSStrike on example.com/example?example= (for the parameter example), it is certain (10/10 certainty) that the payload %3Chtml%3E%3Cscript%20onpointerenter%3Dconfirm()%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E is an XSS vulnerability.
URL-decoded, this becomes <html><script onpointerenter=confirm()></script>, meaning that a 'confirm' option should appear when my cursor goes... somewhere...
I have tried running it, and moving my cursor randomly around the page, but to no avail.

Is there a specify location that should trigger the confirm box?
Could there be something else stopping the XSS?


You added onpointerenter to an element attribute of a script tag?  Why? script tags are non-rendered ... there is nothing to move your cursor over.

This isn't about security. It's purely about how Javascript/HTML/DOM works.

@CaffeineAddiction I did not create this payload, XSStrike did. And obviously because it is a program it only looks for reflections and not the UI needed to trigger the XSS. So <script> is probably just its default. What I wanted to know is whether it could have been triggered a different event (such as <div>) instead, without naming such element. Can XSS scripts change how JS on a page works after it has been reflected but before it has been triggered?

@security_paranoid: ". Can XSS scripts change how JS on a page works after it has been reflected but before it has been triggered? " - I have trouble understanding what you ask here. Reflected XSS is simply the page with attacker controlled parts in it and these parts being on locations where they get treated as script. Insofar reflected XSS is a special kind of HTML injection using the URL - special in that it is not only HTML but also script. So the part "after it has been reflected" vs. "before it has been triggered" is the rendering of the injected HTML by the browser.

I think it's assuming the script tag will be filtered out and you'd be left with   (Or the end result is that...)

@browsermator Thanks… that’s strange though, but you have a good point…

It's a pure programming question. It's off-topic on Security SE. I suggest to close it.
